# JOIN query in MySQL produces wrong result

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have two tables `complaints` and `complaints_reply` in my MySQl database. *Users can add complaints which are stored in complaints the complaints reply are stored in complaints_reply table.* I am trying to JOIN both these table contents on a specific condition. Before I mention what I am trying to get and the problem I faced, I will explain the structure of these two tables first.

**NB**: The person who adds complaints is complaint owner & person who adds a complaint reply is complaint replier. Complaint owner can also add replies. So he can either be the complaint owner or the complaint replier. The two tables have a one-to-many relationship. A complaint can have more than one complaint reply. `member_id` in `complaint` table represents **complaint owner** & `mem_id` in `complaints_reply` represent **complaint replier**

**DESIRED OUTPUT**:
Join the two tables and fetch values and show the complaint and complaint’s reply as a single result set. But the condition is kinda tricky. **The last added complaint reply from the complaints_reply table should be fetched for the complaint in complaints table in such a way that the complaint owner should not be the complaint replier.** I use `posted_date` & `posted_time` from `complaints_reply` table to fetch the last added complaint reply for a complaint & that complaint replier has to be shown in the result set.

So, from the sample data the tables contain now, the output that I should get is:

```
+------+---------+----------+-------------+-------------------+
| id   | title   |member_id |last_replier |last_posted_dt     |
+------+---------+----------+-------------+-------------------+
|    1 | x       | 1000     |2002         | 2015-05-2610:11:17|
|    2 | y       | 1001     |1000         | 2015-05-2710:06:16|
+------+---------+----------+-------------+-------------------+
```

But what I got is:

```
+------+---------+----------+-------------+-------------------+
| id   | title   |member_id |last_replier |last_posted_dt     |
+------+---------+----------+-------------+-------------------+
|    1 | x       | 1000     |1001         | 2015-05-2610:11:17|
|    2 | y       | 1001     |2000         | 2015-05-2710:06:16|
+------+---------+----------+-------------+-------------------+
```

The date is correct, but the returned complaint replier `last_replier` is wrong.

**This is my query**.

```
SELECT com.id,
       com.title,
       com.member_id,
       last_comp_reply.last_replier,
       last_comp_reply.last_posted_dt
FROM complaints com
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT c.id AS complaint_id,
          c.member_id AS parent_mem_id,
          cr.mem_id AS last_replier,
          max(cr.posted_dt) AS last_posted_dt
   FROM
     (SELECT cr.complaint_id,cr.mem_id,c.id,c.member_id,(CONCAT(cr.posted_date,cr.posted_time)) AS posted_dt
      FROM complaints_reply cr,
           complaints c
      WHERE cr.complaint_id=c.id
        AND cr.mem_id!=c.member_id
      GROUP BY cr.complaint_id,
               cr.mem_id,
               posted_dt)cr,
        complaints c
   WHERE cr.complaint_id=c.id
   GROUP BY cr.complaint_id,
            c.id,
            c.member_id) AS last_comp_reply ON com.id=last_comp_reply.complaint_id
```

Table structure for table `complaints`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `complaints` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `posted_date` date NOT NULL,
  `posted_time` time NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

Indexes for table `complaints`

```
ALTER TABLE `complaints`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

AUTO_INCREMENT for table `complaints`

```
ALTER TABLE `complaints`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
```

Dumping data for table `complaints`

```
INSERT INTO `complaints` (`id`, `title`, `member_id`, `posted_date`, `posted_time`) VALUES
(1, 'x', 1000, '2015-05-05', '02:06:15'),
(2, 'y', 1001, '2015-05-14', '02:08:10');
```

Table structure for table `complaints_reply`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `complaints_reply` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `complaint_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comments` text NOT NULL,
  `mem_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `posted_date` date NOT NULL,
  `posted_time` time NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```

Indexes for table `complaints_reply`

```
ALTER TABLE `complaints_reply`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

AUTO_INCREMENT for table `complaints_reply`

```
ALTER TABLE `complaints_reply`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=10;
```

Dumping data for table `complaints_reply`

```
INSERT INTO `complaints_reply` (`id`, `complaint_id`, `comments`, `mem_id`, `posted_date`, `posted_time`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'reply1', 2000, '2015-05-08', '02:07:08'),
(2, 1, 'reply2', 2001, '2015-05-06', '06:05:08'),
(3, 1, 'reply3', 1000, '2015-05-14', '02:12:13'),
(4, 2, 'hola', 1000, '2015-05-27', '10:06:16'),
(5, 2, 'hello', 2000, '2015-05-04', '03:09:09'),
(6, 2, 'gracias', 1001, '2015-05-31', '06:12:18'),
(7, 1, 'reply4', 1001, '2015-01-04', '04:08:12'),
(8, 2, 'puta', 1001, '2015-06-13', '06:12:18'),
(9, 1, 'reply5', 1000, '2015-06-01', '04:08:12'),
(10, 1, 'reply next', 2002, '2015-05-26', '10:11:17');
```

**P.S.**

To give an idea about what my query is all about, I'll explain the sub query that is used to combine the tables & give result based on the condition: complaint owner should not be the complaint replier is:

```
SELECT cr.complaint_id,
       cr.mem_id,
       c.id,
       c.member_id,
       (CONCAT(cr.posted_date,cr.posted_time)) AS posted_dt
FROM complaints_reply cr,
     complaints c
WHERE cr.complaint_id=c.id
  AND cr.mem_id!=c.member_id
GROUP BY cr.complaint_id,
         cr.mem_id,
         posted_dt
```

And the result for this is:

```
+--------------+---------+----------+-------------+-------------------+
| complaint_id | mem_id  | id       |member_id    |     posted_dt     |
+--------------+---------+-------   +-------------+-------------------+
|    1         | 1001    | 1        |1000         | 2015-01-0404:08:12|
|    1         | 2000    | 1        |1000         | 2015-05-0802:07:08|
|    1         | 2001    | 1        |1000         | 2015-05-0606:05:08|
|    1         | 2002    | 1        |1000         | 2015-05-2610:11:17|
|    2         | 1000    | 2        |1001         | 2015-05-2710:06:16|
|    2         | 2000    | 2        |1001         | 2015-05-0403:09:09|
+--------------+---------+----------+-------------+-------------------+
```

*`member_id` here represents complaint owner and `mem_id` represents complaint replier*

The inner query gives the result based on the condition, then everything after this goes haywire. I don't know where I made mistake. The complaint replies added by complaint owner is not fetched in this table. So far so good. Is there any alternative way to get the result from here?

Comment: side question - why are you doing `ALTER TABLE` to do your `PRIMARY KEY`/`Index` and `AUTO_INCREMENT`? Why not just do that in your table declaration?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101111/mysql-join-query-produces-wrong-result/101114#101114

Answer (score 0):

This query gives the result.

```
SELECT com.id AS complaint_id,
       com.member_id AS parent_mem_id,
       crep.mem_id AS last_replier,
       crl.last_posted_dt
FROM complaints com
LEFT JOIN complaints_reply crep ON com.id=crep.complaint_id
JOIN
  (SELECT cr.complaint_id,
          max(CONCAT(cr.posted_date,'_',cr.posted_time)) AS last_posted_dt
   FROM complaints_reply cr,
        complaints c
   WHERE cr.complaint_id=c.id
     AND cr.mem_id!=c.member_id
   GROUP BY cr.complaint_id)crl ON CONCAT(crep.posted_date,'_',crep.posted_time)=crl.last_posted_dt
AND crep.complaint_id=crl.complaint_id
```